# How to write in .evtx file c#

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I want to write event log. I have performed a query. And its returning expected result. Now, I want to write in that result in evtx file.

here is my code:

```
List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
for (EventRecord eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
eventInstance != null; eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent())
{
    eventList.Add(eventInstance);
}
```

How to pass this eventList to write in evtx file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am mentioning the code below to divide the event:

```
 eventRecordList = null;
 remoteEventRecordList = Xmlcollection.Cast<Control.Common.Enums.EventViewerDetails>().ToList();
 var distinctLevels = (from row in remoteEventRecordList.AsEnumerable()
                       let value = row.Level
                       select value).Distinct();
 foreach (var remoteItem in distinctLevels)
 {
     if (!AvailbleFilterOptionsObservableCollection.Any(i => i.Name == GetLevelName(Convert.ToByte(remoteItem))))
     {
         AvailbleFilterOptionsObservableCollection.Add(new FilteredData
         {
             Name = GetLevelName(Convert.ToByte(remoteItem)),
             Level = Convert.ToByte(remoteItem),
             IsSelected = true
         });
     }
 }
```